# How to evaluate following integral?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

Suppose the integral
$$
\tag 1 I = \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx \int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dy}{\tau - \cos (2x) -2\cos(x)\cos(y)}, \quad t > 3
$$
How to evaluate it in terms of elliptic integral?

My attemption.

I made the substitution 
$$
\cos(x) = t, \quad \cos(y) = k
$$
My integral then took the form
$$
I = 4\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\frac{1}{\tau +1 -2x^2-2xy} =
$$
$$
=4\pi \int \limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)((\tau+1-2x^2)^{2} - 4x^2)}} = |x = \sqrt{u}|
$$
$$
=4\pi \int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-u)u((\tau + 1 - 2u)^2 - 4u)}}
$$
But I don't see how it reduces to elliptic integral. Could You help me?

P.S. The elliptic integral from the answer has terrible argument
$$
k = \frac{4(2\tau+3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{2\tau+3}-1))^{3}(\sqrt{2\tau+3}+3})}
$$

**An edit**. The integral is taken.

Comment: Do u know the book ''Green's functions in Quantum Physics'' by Economou? I'm almost sure that u can find this or a very related integral in there.

Comment: @tired: there are cases of simpler integrals there.

Comment: there are canonical transformations (of moebius type) to transform this kind of integrals into standard elliptic form. you can find them here for example in the
"Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists" by Friedman and Bird

Comment: @tired : thank You, I'll try to handle them.