# How to evaluate the series $\sum_{i,j,k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(i+j+k)!}{i!j!k!}\right)^2x^{-i-j-k} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, hypergeometric-function

Suppose the series
$$
\Gamma (x) =\sum_{i,j,k=0}^{\infty}\frac{((i+j+k)!)^2}{(i!)^2(j!)^2(k!)^2}x^{-i-j-k}
$$
How to evaluate it?

It is claimed that for $x <3$ this function converges to elliptic integral of the first kind, precisely see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713436/how-to-evaluate-following-integral) question.

Comment: What does the variable $t$ have to do with anything? And do you write $\Gamma(t)$ as an indication that this actually sums to the Gamma function, or is that just a choice for a name of a function?

Comment: Sorry, I meaned dependence on $x$, not on $t$.

Comment: A very partial answer. Using $r!=\Gamma(r+1)=\int_0^\infty dt\ t^r e^{-t}$ (where $\Gamma$ is the Euler's gamma), you may perhaps recast your sum for $x>0$ as (call it $T(x)$)
$$ 
T(x)=\sum_{i,j,k=0}^{\infty}\frac{((i+j+k)!)^2}{(i!)^2(j!)^2(k!)^2}x^{-i-j-k}
=\iint_0^\infty dt dt' e^{-t-t'}\sum_{i,j,k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(t t')^{i+j+k}}{(i!)^2(j!)^2(k!)^2}x^{-i-j-k}
$$
$$
\iint_0^\infty dt dt' e^{-t-t'}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(t t'/x)^{i}}{(i!)^2}\right)^3=\iint_0^\infty dt dt' e^{-t-t'}I_0^3\left(\frac{2\sqrt{t t'}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\ ,
$$
where $I_0$ is a Bessel function.

Comment: ...which makes me suspect that your sum diverges badly.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo : it is claimed that it converges for $x > 3$. Also it is claimed that this sum can be presented in the form of complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo : sorry, converges.

Comment: Ok this is indeed possible. I would add this bit of information to the body of your question, though. The integral with Bessel looks doable with some (a lot?) of work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get elliptic representation, but there is a hypergeometric one:
$$\sum_{i,j,k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(i+j+k)!}{i!j!k!}\right)^2x^{-i-j-k}=
\frac{x}{x-3}{}_2F_1\left[\frac13,\frac23;1;\frac{27(x-1)}{(x-3)^3}\right].$$

Comment: Thank You! This is sufficient for me.